# How can I tell if a USB-C portable monitor is usable with a particular laptop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, acer-aspire, displayport, usb-c, displaylink

I have an Acer Aspire R15 (Did not get it from Amazon, but [here's the product link](https://smile.amazon.com/Acer-Aspire-15-R5-571TG-78G8-i7-7500U/dp/B01M8OKROA/ref=sr_1_5?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1516029452&sr=1-5&keywords=acer%20aspire&refinements=p_n_size_browse-bin%3A2423841011%2Cp_n_feature_four_browse-bin%3A2289792011%2Cp_n_feature_five_browse-bin%3A13580791011)) and I want to purchase an external, portable monitor because as a Senior in Computer Science and professional programmer, another monitor would be absolutely amazing for productivity.  I want to get a portable one because I frequently need to go to my in-laws and still need to get work done.  I don't have a specific one in mind, but [let's use this as an example](https://smile.amazon.com/ASUS-MB168B-1366x768-Portable-Monitor/dp/B071S84ZW7/ref=sr_1_4?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1516029519&sr=1-4&keywords=portable%2Bmonitor&th=1).

It appears that this monitor only requires DisplayLink drivers if you connect over standard USB-A.  If using USB-C (which the laptop has), then the DisplayLink drivers would not be needed.  I thought USB-C was the same as USB-A, but with a different, reversible, connector.

What is my 'smoking gun' to determine if this monitor (or another, similar to it) would be compatible with a laptop that doesn't specifically mention DisplayLink?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have the same issue, already returned one screen as I just couldn't get it working with my desktop (DisplayPort, HDMI, USB A).

Comment: Sorta, yeah.  The chipset has to support "USB C Alt Mode".  A manufacturer can choose to support it or not, so you just have to look to see if the laptop in question supports it.  The garbage part is that most manufacturers do not list support, even if it's got it, so you may have to do some deep digging or find someone else with the same laptop.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

As adequate external Windows display, you can apply any new Android (v5+) smartphone / Tablet and Spacedesk https://spacedesk.net/ application.
The screen resolution will be the same as on the smartphone (or lower, use app settings). Wi-Fi connection (one TCP/IP network).

Comment: I've used Spacedesk, but the older I get, the less my eyeballs work.  :)  A nice 15"+ monitor would be far preferable because of that.  Good idea, though!